# Why random number generation using parallel processing makes different results even though they have same seed?

Tags: c, openmp

I'm studying parallel processing with openMP on C.

I made simple random number tester with fixed seed value for testing same random number sequence by several different method.

This is a part of rng tester which is not using parallel processing

```
  //1. Single thread
  //set seed value
  init_genrand(2020);

  int fk[33] = {0};

  for(int i=0;i<31250;i++){
    int x = genrand_int32();
    int count = 0;

    for(int j=0;j<33;j++){
      if(x & 1) count ++;
      x = x >> 1;
    }

    fk[count]++;
  }

  int sum = 0;
  for(int i=0;i<33;i++){
    printf("fk[%d] = %d\n",i,fk[i]);
    sum += fk[i];
  }
  printf("sum = %d\n",sum);
```

This code always outputs same result because of fixed seed value of rng function.

However, this code which uses parallel processing does not.

```
  //2. Multi Threads
  //set seed
  init_genrand(2020);

  int fkMulti[33] = {0};

  int count = 0;
  int x = 0;

  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    #pragma omp for private(count, x) reduction(+:fkMulti[:33])
    for(int i=0;i<31250;i++)
    {
      count = 0;
      x = genrand_int32();

      for(int j=0;j<33;j++){
        if(x & 1) count ++;
        x = x >> 1;
      }
      fkMulti[count]++;
    }
  }

  int sumMulti = 0;
  for(int i=0;i<33;i++){
    printf("fkMulti[%d] = %d\n",i,fkMulti[i]);
    sumMulti += fkMulti[i];
  }
  printf("sum = %d\n",sumMulti);
```

Both of them generate 32bit random number 31,250 times, and count how many 1 bit each random number has by shift operator.
But the second one works different to the first one.

Results changes every time I run compiled file.

I also checked Rng function( genrand_int32() ) was excuted 31250 times in those two codes.

Why does it happen even though same seed always makes same result?

Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: It must not be re-entrant.

Comment: Just a WAG, but are you sure the seed stays the same in all the threads? Try moving the call to `init_genrand` to after the `#pragma omp`s

Comment: You need to read up on Parallel Random Number generation; you could reasonably start with "Parallel Random Numbers, As Easy as 1,2,3" http://www.thesalmons.org/john/random123/papers/random123sc11.pdf (and then note that various maths libraries implement their algorithm...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when multi-threading, each thread is making a modification to the internal "random" numbers. The way the rand function works is that it takes the output of the random number generated and uses it as the seed for the next random number to be generated. Because of this, if you have two threads running parallel, one thread may modify the random numbers at inconsistent times, and the resulting random number is used as a seed for the other thread, creating unpredictable results (race condition). You may be able to fix this by only calling srand() once at the very start of the program.

Hope this helps!

Comment: What if I don't care about the predictability of RNGs? Does unsynchronous sharing of RNG seeds have any benefits to performance?